# How can create carousel with margin in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, carousel

I want to create a carousel that Looks like the photo below.
[carousel photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BueFT.png)

this shows the carousel and carousel created with some photos with different widths.
I want the carousel to be moved by the margin of each photo width.
my codes work seem correct but the carousel does not work :(
Which part of the codes are wrong??

this is my Html codes :

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="./previous.png" alt="" class="previous">
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="images">
                <div> <img class="img" src="./images/avatar_1.png" alt="" width="50px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_2.png" alt="" width="100px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_3.png" alt="" width="150px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_4.png" alt="" width="100px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_5.png" alt="" width="200px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_6.png" alt="" width="100px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_7.png" alt="" width="140px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_8.png" alt="" width="180px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_9.png" alt="" width="190px"></div>
                <div><img class="img" src="./images/avatar_10.png" alt="" width="100px"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <img src="./next.png" alt="" class="next">
</div>
```

and this is my CSS codes :

```
.frame {

width: 350px;

height: 150px;

overflow: hidden;

margin: 0px 20px;

border-radius: 10px;}

.carousel{

overflow: hidden;

background-color: rgb(100, 98, 98);

border-radius: 10px;

margin-left: auto;

margin-right: auto;

position: relative;

width: 100%;}

.images{

display: flex;

height: auto;

position: relative;

width: 100%;

height: 100%;}



.imgs{

height: 130px;

margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;

border-radius: 5px;}
```

and this is my Javascript codes:

```
    let images = document.querySelector(".images")
    let next = document.querySelector(".next")
    let previous = document.querySelector(".previous")
    let carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel")
    let img = document.querySelectorAll(".img")
    
    next.addEventListener("click", RightClick)
    let count = 0
    
    
    function RightClick() {
        if (count < 40) {
            let widthImage = img[count].width
            moveRight(widthImage)
            count++
        
        }
    }
    
    function moveRight(widthImage) {
    
        images.style.marginRight = widthImage + "px"
    
    }
    
    previous.addEventListener(LefttClick)
    
    
    function LefttClick() {
        if (count < 40) {
            let widthImage = img[count].width
            moveRight(widthImage)
            count++
        
        }
    }
    
    function moveLeft(widthImage) {
    
        images.style.marginLeft = widthImage + "px"
        
    }
```

important: this is necessary to carousel moved by a margin every click on next or prev button
important 2 = The margin should be the size of the photos

Comment: Check out the setting of the width attributes. And then check what actual value you are getting when you calculate widthImage (use console.log to show you the values).

Comment: I checked out all of them you say but they are correct and exactly get the width of the image